# Worin liegt der Unterschied zwischen "Grund für etw." und "Grund zu etw."?

Tags: preposition

Gibt es eigentlich einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung oder ist es nur ein grammatischer Unterschied, wo nach *für* der Akkusativ kommt, und nach *zu* der Dativ?

Comment: Hallo Abdelrahman Ahmed! Leider verstehe ich deine Frage nicht. Im Titel schreibst du von "Grund für etwas" und "Grund zu etwas". In deiner Frage fragst du aber nach dem Unterschied zwischen "für + Akk." und "für + Dativ". Kannst du deine Frage nochmal genauer stellen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bei der Verwendung der Präposition "**Grund zu(r)**" (mit *haben* oder *geben*) ändert sich die Bedeutung des Wortes Grund in Richtung **Anlass**,
wohingegen "**Grund für**" mehr eine Bedeutung in Richtung **Ursache** impliziert.

Zwei Beispiele:

> Der enorme CO2-Ausstoß ist ein Grund für den Klimawandel

Bei diesem Satz passt "Grund zu" nicht.

Dem gegenübergestellt:

> Wir haben Grund zur Annahme dass der Klimawandel durch den Menschen verursacht wird.

Comment: In Anbetracht der Tatsache, dass *Ursache* und *Anlass* - vgl. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Anlass) - Synonyme sind, lässt mich diese Antwort etwas ratlos zurück.

Comment: @guidot _Anlass_ und _Ursache_ sind nur teilweise Synonyme. Ich denke, _Anlass_ bezeichnet stärker das Situative, die Gelegenheit. Im klassischen Beispiel _X ist ein guter Anlass, Y zu tun_, lässt sich _Anlass_ nur sperrig durch _Ursache_ ersetzen. 
Ähnlich _etw. zum Anlass nehmen, etw. zu tun_. Auch wird bspw. sinnvollerweise zwischen dem Anlass (die Ermordung Franz Ferdidands) und den Ursachen des 1. Weltkriegs unterschieden. Vielleicht könnte der Unterschied in der Antwort noch deutlicher herausgearbeitet werden.

Comment: Zum Unterschied zwischen "Ursache" und "Anlass", siehe https://www.helpster.de/ursache-und-anlass-unterschied_192200

Answer (score 1):

**Grund für** ist bindend. Es umschreibt eine zwingend ursachliche Verbindung.
Grund für Folge ist Ursache.

**Grund zu** ist das nicht. Es motiviert zwar, aber ist nicht ursachlich bindend.
Man kann Grund haben zu handeln aber sich dann doch zu beherrschen wissen.

*Lern nie Deutsch von ein Holländer. Die wissen zwar wo der Hammer hängt, aber das will nichts heißen.*

Answer (score 0):

(Soweit ich die Frage verstehe)

Es gibt keinen Bedeutungsunterschied, aber zwei Satzmuster:

1. Etwas **gibt** Grund **zur** + Dativ, z. B. *Der Truppenaufmarsch in Belarus gibt Grund zur Besorgnis*.
2. Etwas **ist** Grund **für** + Akkusativ, z. B. *Der Grund für die Verspätung ist Weichenstörung.*

Der Fall, also ob Dativ oder Akkusativ, hängt hier nur von der verwendeten Präposition ab.